# How can I bring the price in my website?

Tags: e-commerce

**Hello nice to meet you all**
I need to shortcode bring me latest price from another website to my website.
Example>Amazon after 3 days changed the price of a product to $ 10 My website also change the price to $ 10 automatically

Comment: I want something like this https://pcpartpicker.com/product/J9X2FT/intel-core-i3-7100-39ghz-dual-core-processor-bx80677i37100

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Amazon API to retrieve info about anything. Here's the link to get you started https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/getting-started/